# Pull unique data from a database - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, distinct

I'm looking to query a table that contains messages, organised with a sender and receiver. I would like to create a query to only return each combination of sender and receiver once. I currently have data stored in a database like so:

| sender | receiver |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 |

The output I am looking for is as so:

```
1 | 2
3 | 4
```

Is this possible? If so, any hints in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One option uses `least()` and `greatest()`, and `distinct`:

```
select distinct least(sender, receiver) as user1, greatest(sender, receiver) as user2
from mytable
```